# How to recover public key password?

Tags: ubuntu, password

I created a new instance of a server on my VPS provider and when I was doing the initial server setup it prompted me for a password, which I don't remember. Is there anything I can do in this situation?  My local computer is a mac.The remote server is Ubuntu

```
ssh root@162.XXX.XXX.XXX
The authenticity of host '162.XXX.XXX.XXX)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 37:07:d5:0b:7b
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '162.XXX.XXX.XXX' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@162.XXX.XXX.XXX's password:
```

Comment: That is not a public key password. Contact your hosting provider for assistance.

Comment: It's not a password set by the hosting provider. It was set on my Mac to be entered whenever I ssl into a server

Comment: No, that is NOT the password you are being prompted for there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I assumed it was a password I set for my ssh keys since the instance of this server was just created and I had never set a root password

Comment: Just because you didn't set a password, doesn't mean your VPS provider didn't set one. Also, if no one set a password and there is no key set up, you'll get a password prompt but won't be able to log in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a normal password prompt, not a public key passphrase prompt. Check you VPS hosting provider console to see if they provide self help password resets. Failing that you'll have to contact them to get them to help you.

---

If this were asking for the passphrase for the public key it would look like this

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Comment: that's a new instance of the server. I hadn't set a password for the root user yet. The instance was just created....

Comment: @Michael: I don't know what you're arguing about, that's clearly a password prompt from 162... asking for the root accounts password.

Comment: I'm not arguing. I'm just telling you i hadn't set a root password (it's a new server), so I'm surprised it's asking for one.